# svelte animation - unwanted overlapping content when removing items from the keyed each block

Tags: javascript, svelte

I plan to add notifications to an existing svelte app to show errors, warnings and info messages to the users. I started with a simple idea to show a list of message box that can be clicked away or disappear after some seconds. No problem with that, but when I started to add transitions and animations to make it look a bit more pleasant, I got stuck. Here is a simplified REPL version that demonstrates the issue: https://svelte.dev/repl/dadfc61322b74a24ace88b368d5fdbe9?version=3.23.2

Click the button to make some boxes appear, click on boxes and they are removed, when all are gone, the button comes back.

When a user clicks on message boxes, then the lower part of the page jumps up before the box is removed. The effect becomes visible, when you remove boxes from the top.

What I'd like to have is the lower part of the page sliding up in sync with the list element. Or, at least, jumping up *after* the animation is done and not when it starts.

Does anyone spot an error I made on the REPL or knows how to achieve that with svelte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier to achieve with the `slide` transition than with the `animate:` directive:

```
import {flip} from 'svelte/animate';
import {slide} from 'svelte/transition';
```

```
<div animate:flip={{delay: 1000, duration: 500}}>
<div out:slide={{delay: 1000, duration: 500}}>
  <Message {text} on:click="{() => remove(text)}" />
</div>
```

Note that this doesn't work well with the `margin` style on the `<Message>` component, because of how margins work (if you remove notification 2, notifications 1 and 3 will have the 8px margin between them and 2 until 2 is finally removed from the DOM, at which point 1 and 3 will snap to only having the 8px margin between each other), so it's better to use padding on the container element around `<Message>`.

Also, with this approach the notification will still be visible until it slides out, which isn't what you want. You need an element *inside* the sliding element to become invisible but stay in the DOM (to keep the correct layout) until the outro, which can be achieved with something like this:

```js
const hide = (node, { duration, delay }) => {
  return {
    duration: duration + delay,
    css: t => `opacity: 0`
  };
};
```

```html
<div class="message-container" out:slide={anim_opts}>
  <div out:hide={anim_opts}>
    <Message {text} on:click="{() => remove(text)}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/4fc52b9e847e450e8173d4bfce5a4274?version=3.23.2).

Comment: Many thanks! That is great and exactly the effect that I had in mind. I first thought that I might solve it with a 'mixed' list that contains all notifications at the beginning and the rest of the page at the end, but that felt far too 'hackish' so I better asked. Now I can try to figure out, how to add a visible 'out' transition to the notification. the 'fly in' works, the 'scale out' is ignored or hidden. But even if i don't find a way: I use that solution in my code. Thanks again!

Comment: I finally understood the magic, took a while to understand the purpose of all the transitions that work together here. And so I managed to add a nice out transition to the notification boxes. Ready to rumble now. https://svelte.dev/repl/eed15558ed364eb09a334f02ba994bd2?version=3.23.2